# I need to make an Ajax call and display the contents of my DB Table,I am using Perl CGI and trying to call Perl script through javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, perl, cgi

for some reason the web console is giving me an error in the document.ready function. It says uncaught syntax error unidentified identifier

This is my cgi script which has the JS which calls the perl script TestAj.pl which returns a json and I am trying to get that data in javascript function getAppointments() by using alert function to display the perl output. But I dont get anything in the alert.

I am new to perl cgi and ajax so please let me know if I am doing something silly. FYI I have tested the perl script on my local machine and it gives me the required output.
Here is my cgi script which contains js and html

```
#!"c:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"
use strict;
use CGI;


my $query = new CGI;


print $query->header( "text/html" );

print <<END_HERE;
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
     getAppointments();
 });
function getAppointments(){
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/cgi-bin/TestAj.pl", // URL of the Perl script
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        }, // success
        error: function() {alert("did not work");}
      });
}
    </script>
    <title>My First CGI Script</title>

  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#FFFFCC">
    <input type="button" value="New" onclick="showDiv()" />
<div id="hideShow" style="display:none;">
<form id="new app" method="POST" action="/cgi-bin/testing.cgi">
<input type="text" name="Date">Date<br>
<input type="text" name="Time">Time<br>
<input type="text" name="Description">Description<br>
<input type="submit" value="Add">
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="hideDiv()" />
</form>
</div>

<p>       </p>
<p>       </p>
<p>       </p>
<form id="search" action="">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" name="searchApp"><br>
</td>
<td>
<input type="submit" value="Search"><form>
</td>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('hideShow').style.display = "block";
}
    function hideDiv() {
   document.getElementById('hideShow').style.display = "none";
}




</script>

</body>
</html>
END_HERE
```

The perl script TestAj.pl is as follows:

```
#!"c:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON; 
use DBI;
use CGI;
our @query_output;
our $row="";
our $dbh="";
our $sth="";
our $dbfile = "";
$dbfile = "sample.db";
our $dsn      = "dbi:SQLite:dbname=$dbfile";
our $cgi = CGI->new;
our $user     = "";
our $password = "";
#print "Content-type: application/json; charset=iso-8859-1\n\n";

$dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password, {
   PrintError       => 0,
   RaiseError       => 1,
   AutoCommit       => 1,
   FetchHashKeyName => 'NAME_lc',
});

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM appointment");
$sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
while ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref ){
push @query_output, $row;
}
   #my ($id,$Date,$Time,$Description) = @row;
   #my $json={{"id":"$id","Date":"$Date","Time":"$Time","Description":"$Description"}}
   # return JSON string
    #print @query_output;
    print $cgi->header(-type => "application/json", -charset => "utf-8");
    print JSON::to_json(\@query_output);

    #print $json;
```

Thanks

Comment: Interesting to see that in your first program you have the (very much not recommended) syntax `$query = new CGI` and in the second you have the (vastly superior) syntax (`$cgi = CGI-->new`). Wondered why you were being so inconsistent.

Comment: Hi Dave, I am quite new to Perl and CGI so I would definitely keep your advice.  I mostly work with Java so I didn't know the right conventions here.

Answer (score 2):

your problem lies in the line

```
print <<END_HERE;
```

as this will interpolate any perl-variables in your code. As You probably dont want to do this, you either have to escape every sigil ($, %, @) or simply change this line to:

```
print <<'END_HERE';
```

HTH
Georg

Comment: Thanks a ton George! Got it!